# Loading the Dynamic values from <string-array> to ListView in Android

Tags: android

> Loading the Dynamic values from  to ListView in Android

it's purpose is:

1. resources is
2. retrieving the 10 items and placing in ListView,and
   Thanks in Adv..

Here is my code

```
public class MainFucntions extends Activity {
ImageButton searchingpacksImg;
EditText searchEntry;
GridView searched_data_grid;
String entry;
String entry_from_db[];
List<String> disp_items_list;
Context context;
ArrayAdapter<String> adp;
int start = 0,limit = 10;
boolean flag_loading = false;
View loadMoreView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.allpackages);
getInits();
sortingOperations();
}
private void sortingOperations() {
searchingpacksImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
searched_data_grid.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
searched_data_grid.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
(context,android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item,disp_items_list));
searched_data_grid.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
}
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int        
totalItemCount) {
Log.e("onScroll First", ""+firstVisibleItem);
Log.e("onScroll totalItemCount", ""+totalItemCount);
Log.e("onScroll visibleItemCount", ""+visibleItemCount);
if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
{
if(flag_loading == false)
{
flag_loading = true;
additems();
}
}
}
private void additems() {
entry = searchEntry.getText().toString();
for(int i = 0 ; i < entry_from_db.length ; i++)
if(entry_from_db[i].contains(entry)){
disp_items_list.add(entry_from_db[i]);
}
flag_loading = false;
}
});
}
});
}
private void getInits() {
context = this;
searchingpacksImg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search);
searchEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searching_field);
searched_data_grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.searched_data);
disp_items_list = new ArrayList<String>();
entry_from_db = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.all_stations_names);
adp =new ArrayAdapter<String>       
(context,android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item,entry_from_db);
searched_data_grid.setAdapter(adp);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Thanx for response,I'm not able place the code of sending the data to ListView,by condition